# How to remove outliers based on number of column values in each row

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am new to data science and trying to solve a course exercise for movie recommender system and I want to drop the **rows** based on total count of values for **columns** for each **row**.

**i.e.**
if someone gave rating to too much movies he should be dropped to filter out the final results.
Though, I found a traditional way of doing it but I am not satisfied as it will be really helpful if someone would help me find a more pythonic way of solving the problem.

Here is the table named `userRatings`

```
title    Zeus and Roxanne (1997)  unknown  Á köldum klaka (Cold Fever) (1994)  
user_id                                                                        
0                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
1                            NaN      4.0                                 NaN  
2                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
3                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
4                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
5                            NaN      4.0                                 NaN  
6                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
7                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
8                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  
9                            NaN      NaN                                 NaN  

[10 rows x 1664 columns]
```

And here is the code i tried to solve the problem:

```
for index in userRatings.index:
     if userRatings.loc[index].count() > 500:
         userRatings = userRatings.drop(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a Pandas DataFrame... if so, one alternative would be something like this:

```
valid_rating_ixs = userRatings.sum(axis=1) <= 500
userRantings_cleaned = userRatings[valid_rating_ixs]
```

Note that in my code above and also your code, you may be including columns that are not ratings (e.g. user_id). Maybe you need to check that you are using only the relevant columns in your data frame